# regex to match domain but not subdomains

Tags: regex

I'm looking to make a basic regex pattern for a url that will exclude any subdomains for soe basic mocking (I know there are some weaknesses in the regex for something more serious)

so for example this works

```
http:\/\/.*\/accounts\/.+
```

it matches my urls so for example

```
http://localhost:8080/accounts/mynewaccount
```

but what I would like it to do is not pickup the 'sub endpoints' so for example I would like it not to match

```
http://localhost:8080/accounts/mynewaccount/address
```

I've tried doing this by adding ^[/] to the end or by adding a surrounding ^ and $ but I don't seem to quite get it ?  Can anyone help ?  The less sophisticated the better really as it is just for mocking end points in a basic set of unit tests

Comment: Use `^http:\/\/\S+\/accounts\/[^\/]+/?$`

Comment: So you don't want to match it at all or just up to the point where 'mynewaccount' ends? Like [`^http:\/\/.*\/accounts\/[^/]+`](https://regex101.com/r/UzESDR/1). Just add the [`$`](https://regex101.com/r/kFA7yA/1) -end string anchor if you need too.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you very much